# powershell code to remotely logg off a user session when a particular event ID is encountered in system logs

Tags: powershell, usb, remote-access, logoff, event-id

I am trying to write a script to remotely log off a user when a particular event ID is encountered. If a user connects a usb drive then event ID 2003 is generated in logs. How can I remotely log off that particular user remotely through powershell?

Comment: You will be monitoring the logs remotely in real-time?

Comment: yes, I am monitoring the logs remotely in real time.

Comment: You can use `Quser.exe` to get the users session ID. Then, you can invoke `logoff.exe` against the ID.

Comment: I commend to your attention the WMI class Win32_OperatingSystem and its Win32Shutdown and Win32ShutdownTracker methods.

Comment: Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'PNP AUDIT' | foreach-object 
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.name-Scriptblock
{
$EventId = 2003
$A = Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational" ; ID = $EventId}
$MachineName = $A.MachineName
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $A.MachineName.).InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown",0)                 The above code is not executing.